# Chrome Extension: How to pass a variable from Content Script to background.html

Tags: jquery, ajax, screen-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I can't figure out how to pass a variable (or an array of variables) from a content script to a background page.  What I'm trying to do is find certain DOM elements with my content script, then send them to my background page so that I can make a cross-domain XMLHttpRequest with them (store them in a database on a different site).

My code is below.  I know that the variable named "serialize" is not being passed (and I don't expect it to based on my current code but have it in there so it's easier to see what I want to do.)  So how can I pass a variable from a content script to a background page?

My Content Script:

```
function onText(data) {
alert("Great Success!!");
};
$("#insertprofile").click(function(){
serialize = $(".certaininputs").serialize();
chrome.extension.sendRequest({'action' : 'insertprofile', 'serialize' : serialize}, onText);
});
```

My Background Page:

```
   <script>
      function insertprofile(serialize) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
              var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              callback(data);
            } else {
              callback(null);
            }
          }
        }
        var url = ('http://mysite.com/storeindatabase.php?' + serialize);
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.send();
      };
      function onRequest(request, sender, serialize) {
        if (request.action == 'insertprofile') {
          insertprofile(serialize);
        }
      };
      chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you checked in the Inspector console if there are any errors? (on the page, and background page)

Answer (score 1):

Did you missing `"...php?serialize=' + serialize)"` on this code:

```
var url = ('http://mysite.com/storeindatabase.php?' + serialize);
```

It's should be like this:

```
var url = ('http://mysite.com/storeindatabase.php?serialize=' + serialize);
```

Comment: The "serialize" variable used in the question represents the intent of what the asker would like. They're looking for a mechanism to pass data from the script to the background page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({'action' : 'insertprofile', 'serialize': serialize}, onText);
```

?

**EDIT**

```
function onRequest(request, sender, callback) {
   if (request.action == 'insertprofile') {
     insertprofile(request.serialize, callback);
   }
};
```

Comment: Hmmm, maybe.  It still doesn't work for me though.  For example, if I change the code to (...php?' + 'name=john'), 'john' is received by the php script and stored in my database.  But if I change it to (...php?' + serialize), the php script receives nothing even though the value of serialize on the content script is name=john.  So I'm pretty sure the variable is still not being passed to the background page.  Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I'm trying to.  I edited my code above to reflect changes I've made based on your help but it still isn't working.

Comment: @John See edit. `request` object would contain your `serialize`

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is accessing the serialize instead of request.serialize.

```
function insertprofile(serialize) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
              var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              callback(data);
            } else {
              callback(null);
            }
          }
        }
        var url = ('http://mysite.com/storeindatabase.php?' + serialize);
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.send();
      };


chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action == 'insertprofile') {
          insertprofile(request.serialize);
          sendResponse({});
  }

});
```